# grep string between backtick

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
`someString` complete(1)
```

I need "someString" that is in between backticks.
tried below but doesn't work.

```
cat file.txt | grep '\`.*\`'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `grep` that supports [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) extension:

```
grep -Po '(?<=`)[^`]*(?=`)' infile
```

or to return  `a` and `c` only for example in `` `a`b`c` ``, [you would do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26966799/4023950):

```
grep -Po '(?<=`)[^`]+(?=`(?:[^`]*`[^`]*`)*[^`]*$)'
```

return everything between pair of backticks.

Tips:
`(?<=...)`: [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
`(?=...)`: [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
`(?:...)`: [non-capturing group](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html?wlr=1).
`` [^`]* ``: any character except a back-tick `` ` ``

---

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'`' '{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i; }' infile
```

Comment: Or use `pcregrep -o1 '\`(.*?)\`'`, or the real thing: `perl -lne 'print for /\`(.*?)\`/g'`

Comment: Note that not all `grep` implementations that have a `-P` option for perl-like regexps implement it using libpcre. With the ast-open implementation, with `-o` (which is also a non-standard extension), you want to make sure the regexp can't match the empty string or you'll run in an infinite loop. GNU `grep` and `pcregrep`, with `-o` don't output the empty matches.

Answer (score 4):

`grep`, by default, returns *lines* matching the expression given.  Your expression would therefore return the whole line as it matches the expression.

Instead of using `grep`, we could use `sed` to edit the lines that contains the string we're after.

Assuming that there is only ever a single backticked string in the line, we can chop off everything before the first backtick, and after the second:

```
$ sed 's/[^`]*`//; s/`.*//' <file.txt
someString
```

Since the backtick is not special in regular expressions, it does not need to be escaped. The backtick *is* special to the shell (it introduces a command substitution), but since we use a single-quoted string, the shell will not treat it as special.

---

One could also match the string between the backticks in a capture group (`\(...\)` in `sed`), and then replace the whole line with it (but personally, I think it makes it a bit harder to read):

```
$ sed 's/[^`]*`\([^`]*\)`.*/\1/' <file.txt
someString
```

All uses of `` [^`] `` in the above expressions mean "some character, which is not a backtick".

---

A totally different approach would be to first remove all backticks, and then remove everything from the blank space onward in the line:

```
$ tr -d '`' <file.txt | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*//'
someString
```

The `[[:blank:]]` character class matches a single space or tab character.

This obviously assumes that the backticked string is a single word with no embedded blank characters, and that it occurs first on the line, as in the example in the question.

---

Turning back to `grep`... If your `grep` has the non-standard (but commonly implemented) `-o` option to return only the bits that matched the expression from each line, then we can use that as so:

```
$ grep -o '`[^`]*`' <file.txt | tr -d '`'
someString
```

This first gets us the backticked string, and then the backticks are removed.  This would behave differently from the approaches with `sed` if there were more than one backticked string per line.  In that case, this would give you back each such string on a line of its own, while the `sed` variations would give you back only the *first* backticked string.

Answer (score 4):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -d'`' -f2  < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

command1

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^`.*`/){gsub("`","",$0);print $i}}}' filename


Above command tested and worked fine
```

Comment: You can’t have tested it very extensively then. Try it with a file containing multiple terms in `\`` pairs...